# How does "sub END" know program has died? (Perl)

Tags: perl

In Perl, how do I make an END subroutine test if Perl has died?

This code works fine and prints "RUNS":

```
sub END {print "RUNS\n"} 
die "TESTING";
```

What variable do I check to see if the script ended normally or died?

I know about %SIG, but surely there's an easier answer here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Test `$?`:

```
END {print $? ? "DIED\n" : "RUNS\n"} 
die "TESTING";
```

Comment: Not quite. `perl -E'END { say "died" if $? } exit(1);'` incorrectly prints `died`. @pavel, @barrycarter

Comment: @ikegami: True, but one could argue that an exit code <> 0 and a die are very much alike...